# How to make comments begin at cursor in Xcode instead of starting at left margin?

Tags: xcode, comments, xcode7, indentation

I like to use indentation and space to add clarity and meaning to comments. I end up wasting a lot of time tabbing my comments to the desired margin. Something tells me these efforts are wasted.

Here is a video showing the process I want to avoid: https://vid.me/Oj5z

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior in xcode 7.1 for swift, obj-c, or header files, nor in playgrounds

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you press return anywhere inside that method shown in your video, the cursor should be indented automatically - no matter what you type.

You can also indent code/comments in sections: highlight several lines, then head over to Editor - Structure - Re-Indent to make the whole section line up automatically, or use the shift left/shift right options from the same menu to move the section manually.